# Getting base domain name php

Tags: php

```php
function getHost($Address) { 
    $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($Address)); 
    return trim($parseUrl[host]
            ? $parseUrl[host] 
            : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl[path], 2))
    ); 
} 

$httpreferer = getHost($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$httpreferer = preg_replace('#^(http(s)?://)?w{3}\.#', '$1', $httpreferer);

echo $httpreferer;
```

I am using this to strip http:// , www and subdomains to return just the host however it returns the following:

```
http://site.google.com ==> google.com
http://google.com      ==> com
```

How do i get it to just remove the subdomain when it exists instead of stripping down to the tld when it doesn't exist?

Comment: This sounds like a very difficult problem because _"subdomain"_ doesn't really mean anything. You're going to have a lot of difficulty with TLDs like `.co.uk` too

Comment: you mean it returns `http://site.google.com` because that wont remove it see  https://regex101.com/r/y1pVjt/1

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks for adding that. I was staring at OP's regular expression and thinking _"but that only removes 'www.'"_

Comment: as far as i can tell the function removes all but the host and subdomain then the preg_replace checks for a www or a period and eliminates all before it leaving the domain however it only seems to work on www. and not on subdomains.

As an example if the referrer is http:// www. site.com the return variable would be site.com  with this however if the referrer is http:// sub.site.com the return would be sub.site.com and its the sub.  i want to remove.

Comment: You would probably be better off getting the host from the URL then parsing the response from a `dig` query or something else. You can get the host from parse_url with one call as well, `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)`

Answer (score 2):

Start with `parse_url` specifically `parse_url($url)['host']`

```
 $arr = parse_url($url);
 echo preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $arr['host'])."\n";
```

Output

```
site.google.com
google.com
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb9f4be1da8b05846b813685bdae9401c3a70ca6)

The Regex for this is just matches `www.` if it's the start of the string, you could probably do this part a few ways, such as with

**No subdomain**

If you don't want any subdomain at all:

```
$arr = parse_url($url)['host'];
echo preg_replace('/^(?:[-a-z0-9_]+\.)?([-a-z0-9_]+\..+)$/', '$1',$arr['host'])."\n";
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8edb02fd3c015a2537679a3f58dde6ebef3c8a9)

**No subdomain, no Country Code**

```
$arr = parse_url($url)['host'];
echo preg_replace('/^(?:[-a-z0-9_]+\.)?([-a-z0-9_]+)(\.[^.]+).*?$/', '$1$2',$arr['host'])."\n";
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/162e789fa58e1218885d8a944e975eda60171da1)

How it works,

Same as the previous one but the domain is separated from the host, and instead of just capturing everything, we capture everything but the `.` and outside the new group we capture everything (confusingly the . is everything here) but with `*?` which means `*` 0 or more times, `?` non-greedy don't take characters from previous expressions.

Or to put it another way.  Capture anything 0 or more times don't steal characters from previous matches.  This way if there is nothing such as `www.google.com` we are only worried about stuff after `.com` then its 0 matches.  But if its `www.google.com.uk` it matches the `.uk`.

**Single Line Answer**.

Some versions of PHP, I forget what ones but the newer ones actually let you do this:

```
   $host = parse_url($url)['host'];
```

So taking the last example we can compress that into one line and remove the variable assignment.

```
  echo preg_replace('/^(?:[-a-z0-9_]+\.)?([-a-z0-9_]+)(\.[^.]+).*?$/', '$1$2',parse_url($url)['host'])."\n";
```

[See it in action](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dda4a1a21c476e60178550b9b6131b2af8d3071e)

That was just for fun!

**Summery**

Using `parse_url` is really the "correct" way to do it.  Or the proper way to start as it removes a lot of the other "stuff" and gives you a good starting place. Anyway this was fun for me ... :) ...  And I needed a break from coding my Website, because it's tedious for me now (It was 8 years old, so I'm redoing it in WordPress, and I've done about a zillion WordPress site) ...

Cheers, hope it helps!

Comment: yes but without the http:// and as you can see the subdomain remains so its a question of what to put in preg_replace to remove subdomains but not the host and that's a problem.

Comment: that code without the protocol actually brought the www back.

Comment: from what i am seeing getting rid of the subdomain from an address is much harder than you'd think it would be. I've looked all over the web and the code above is the only one i have found that removes all i need except for the damn subdomain lol.

Comment: Do you want to remove all the subdomains?

Comment: There I removed some of the unnecessary stuff, and cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer

```
$testAdd = "https://testing.google.co.uk";
$parse = parse_url($testAdd);
$httpreferer = preg_replace("/^([a-zA-Z0-9].*\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,})$/", '$2', $parse['host']);


echo $httpreferer;
```

This will also deal with domain with country TLD

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: you shouldn't post an answer when you post the question, it can be confusing to some users.  Not too mention that regex is "ugly" try this one instead `/^(?:[-a-z0-9_]+\.)?([-a-z0-9_]+\..+)$/`

Comment: it does give the option to post and answer to your own question should you find the solution

Comment: This one will remove the country part `/^(?:[-a-z0-9_]+\.)?([-a-z0-9_]+)(\.[^.]+).*?$/` so `http://site.google.com.uk` becomes `google.com`

Comment: But I don't think you can mark it as Answered.  Which was my point, if there is 4 or 5 answers and as the OP, you post your own answer it's hard to pick that out from the other ones.  A better thing is to as `**SOLVED**` {bold} at the end of the question body and put the answer under that, that way other users don't have to read through all the other posts to figure it out.  That was my point anyway.